# Django on different user login render different html pages

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-users

I am using Django.
I am using inbuilt auth .user of django for person login.
I have extended the auth.user with model profile(containing role and image)

**models.py is as below:**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Profile(models.Model):

ROLE_CHOICES = [
    ('SALES', 'SALES'),
    ('MARKETING', 'MARKETING'),
    ('HR', 'HR'),
    ('PROJECT MANAGER', 'PROJECT MANAGER'),
    ('SUPERVISOR', 'SUPERVISOR'),
]

user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
profile_image = models.FileField(upload_to='img/', default='img/default.png')
role = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=ROLE_CHOICES, blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.user)
```

**This is my views.py on loggingin correct credentials:**
'''

```
class SignView(View):

   def get(self, request):
       return render(request, 'login/login.html')

   def post(self, request):
       email = request.POST.get('email')
       password = request.POST.get('password')
       role = request.POST.get('role')

       # If user doesn't exist return None
       user = User.objects.filter(email=email).first()

       if user is not None:
           # Check password
           correct_password = check_password(password, user.password)

           if correct_password:
               pro = Profile.objects.get(user=user)
               print(pro.role)
               if pro.role == 'Sales':
                   login(request, user)
                   return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('sales:sales-main-dashboard'))
               else:
                   login(request, user)
                   return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('marketing:marketing-main-dashboard'))
            messages.error(request, 'Sorry something went wrong.')
            return render(request, 'login/login.html')
```

'''
For now it works fine for 2 roles i.e if marketing person logs-in then marketing/main-dashboard.html page renders and                                 for sales sales/main-dashboard.html renders but further more when my roles will increase (atleast 30 roles will be there) each time to render differnet pages(for that particular role) I have to give if, elif statements (referring my views).Please give me correct approach.

urls.py for marketing app.

'''

```
app_name = 'marketing'

urlpatterns = [

path('marketing-main-dashboard', login_required(MainDashboardView.as_view()), 
name='marketing-main-dashboard'),
]
```

'''

urls.py for marketing app and sales app.
'''
app_name = 'sales'

urlpatterns = [

```
path('sales-main-dashboard', login_required(MainDashboardView.as_view()), name='sales-main-dashboard'),]
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

You should use token based authentication in your application.
Authentication is the mechanism of associating an incoming request with a set of identifying credentials, such as the user the request came from, or the token that it was signed with.

there are number of authentication schemes out of the box.
The best one which I found is `JSON Web Token Authentication` (any way you can use whatever you wish for your application).

in jwt(Json web token) you need to generate and send the jwt(token) while user logging in, specifically in login API response, and the same token needs to be sent back from the client in the Header of the request, specifically it should be wrapped in key Authorization.

`Authorization : Bearer paste_token_received_in_login_api`

so finally validate this token and let user access to the respected resource.

kindly elaborate your question if you feel this not answer your question. so that someone can answer.

Comment: Puttamarigowda M S sir please check my queston again, I am a fresher in this and I am not using rest-api for now.